# Difference between dynamic model and static model

Tags: modelling

I have been going through types of models in Spatial Modelling.

- As far as I know, Dynamic modeling is done on temporal data while static modeling is time independent i.e. it works on single data set. Is this concept correct?
- Also I could not find appropriate examples of the two related to GIS (Geography Information System)

Comment: What definitions of Static and Dynamic Modelling have you found through searches?  Your second dot point seems to be a separate question and too broad for our focussed Q&A format.

Comment: @PolyGeo 

[link](http://www.differencebetween.com/difference-between-static-and-vs-dynamic-modelling/) I have gone through this web page but am still not clear what could be the example of static and dynamic model

Comment: @PolyGeo can you help me understand with example like can NDVI (Normalized Differential Vegetation Index) a type of static model?

Comment: I don't work with NDVI but I suggest you widen your searching e.g. http://www.google.com/search?q=static+dynamic+model+gis or from this site: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/136878/how-to-calculate-water-accumulated-in-each-cell-using-qgis/136890#136890

Answer (score 1):

```
Static modeling is used to specify the structure of the 
objects that exist in the problem statement. These can be
expressed using:
 CLASS, OBJECT and USECASE diagrams. 

Dynamic modeling refers to represent the object 
interactions during runtime. These can be
expressed using:
SEQUENCE,ACTIVITY, COLLABORATION diagrams
```

find more here:http://www.slideshare.net/100arab/dynamic-and-static-modeling